# Youtube Video Background to blocks inside a webpage

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I want to setup YouTube videos as background of blocks inside my webpage using JavaScript. There i need the videos to play in full width mode. Also I need to give options such as auto-play, loop and mute.

I have a script there I can give background videos with loop and autoplay functionalities, but can't give full width and mute functionalities. In my script I generate an iframe like the following sample code

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/youtube_id_here?autoplay=1&loop=1">
</iframe>
```

How can I setup code with auto-play, full-width, loop and mute functionality,.

Help please

Comment: Check my iFrameless/JS/CSS only solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41616179/youtube-video-header-background/45377998#45377998

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code

```html
<div style="position: fixed; z-index: -99; width: 100%; height: 100%">
  <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" 
    src="https://youtube.com/embed/gkTb9GP9lVI?autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not looking for positioning the video in background. I just want the options for mute and full-width. :)

Comment: You have full-width in code width 100% and hidden controls.. ;>
volume control is available only in api.. so use a iframe api to do this :)

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference