# Youtube Video Header Background

Tags: html, css, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to create a few website templates to help me improve my front end development skills, as I'm currently far better at rear end work.

I'm trying to somewhat replicate the style of my own website (https://thomas-smyth.co.uk/), which is a simple Bootstrap template. However, instead of using a static photo in the header, I want to replace it with a Youtube video. I began by cutting down the template used in my website and have stripped it down to as little as I think I can get it without breaking the header.

I have found a few pieces of code around the place to show how to set a Youtube video as background of the overall page, but not the background for specific sections of the page. How can I do this? Note - It has to be streamed from YouTube as my hosts don't allow me to host video's on their servers.

My current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">

    <title>Group Name | Home</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">

    <!-- Custom -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/mainstyle.css">

</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <div class="header-content">
            <div class="header-content-inner">
                <h1>This is going once vid is done.</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="bg-primary">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">Placeholder!</h2>
                    <p>I should have found a witty comment to put here, but I'm just gonna put "Placeholder" instead.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/mainscript.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Merriweather', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}
p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.bg-primary {
  background-color: #F05F40;
}
section {
  padding: 100px 0;
}
.no-padding {
  padding: 0;
}

header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: auto;
    background-image: url('../img/header.jpg');
    background-position: 0% 80%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
header .header-content {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 100px 15px 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  header {
    min-height: 100%;
  }
  header .header-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    padding: 0 50px;
  }
  header .header-content .header-content-inner {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}
.section-heading {
  margin-top: 0;
}

::-moz-selection {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: none;
  background: #222222;
}
::selection {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: none;
  background: #222222;
}
img::selection {
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
}
img::-moz-selection {
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
}
body {
  webkit-tap-highlight-color: #222222;
}
```

**Best I have so far (does whole page's background)**

```
<div class="video-background">
    <div class="video-foreground">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/W0LHTWG-UmQ?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=W0LHTWG-UmQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.video-background {
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: -99;
}
.video-foreground,
.video-background iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground { height: 300%; top: -100%; }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground { width: 300%; left: -100%; }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've created a simple example with Youtube video background using direct links to video stream (JS/CSS only solution). Feel free to check it on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/350D/uq1vvavf/). Also, you can update public Google Image proxy URL to any public or your own CORS proxy.

```js
var vid = "FUUw3zNTXH8",
    streams,
    video_tag = document.getElementById("video");

fetch("https://images" + ~~(Math.random() * 33) + "-focus-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy?container=none&url=" + encodeURIComponent("https://www.youtube.com/watch?hl=en&v=" + vid)).then(response => response.text()).then(function(data) {
    if (data) {
        streams = parse_youtube_meta(data);
        video_tag.src = streams['hls'] || streams['720pna'] || streams['480pna'] || streams['720p'] || streams['480p'] || streams['360p'] || streams['240p'] || streams['144p'];
    } else {
        alert('Youtube API Error');
    }
});

function parse_youtube_meta(rawdata) {


    var regex = /(?:ytplayer\.config\s*=\s*|ytInitialPlayerResponse\s?=\s?)(.+?)(?:;var|;\(function|\)?;\s*if|;\s*if|;\s*ytplayer\.|;\s*<\/script)/gmsu;


    rawdata = rawdata.split('window.getPageData')[0];
    rawdata = rawdata.replace('ytInitialPlayerResponse = null', '');
    rawdata = rawdata.replace('ytInitialPlayerResponse=window.ytInitialPlayerResponse', '');
    rawdata = rawdata.replace('ytplayer.config={args:{raw_player_response:ytInitialPlayerResponse}};', '');


    var matches = regex.exec(rawdata);
    var data = matches && matches.length > 1 ? JSON.parse(matches[1]) : false;

    console.log(data);

    var streams = [],
        result = {};

    if (data.streamingData && data.streamingData.adaptiveFormats) {
        streams = streams.concat(data.streamingData.adaptiveFormats);
    }

    if (data.streamingData && data.streamingData.formats) {
        streams = streams.concat(data.streamingData.formats);
    }

    streams.forEach(function(stream, n) {
        var itag = stream.itag * 1,
            quality = false,
            itag_map = {
                18: '360p',
                22: '720p',
                37: '1080p',
                38: '3072p',
                82: '360p3d',
                83: '480p3d',
                84: '720p3d',
                85: '1080p3d',
                133: '240pna',
                134: '360pna',
                135: '480pna',
                136: '720pna',
                137: '1080pna',
                264: '1440pna',
                298: '720p60',
                299: '1080p60na',
                160: '144pna',
                139: "48kbps",
                140: "128kbps",
                141: "256kbps"
            };
        //if (stream.type.indexOf('o/mp4') > 0) console.log(stream);
        if (itag_map[itag]) result[itag_map[itag]] = stream.url;
    });

    if (data.streamingData && data.streamingData.hlsManifestUrl) {
        result['hls'] = data.streamingData.hlsManifestUrl;
    }

    return result;
};
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: #444;
    overflow: hidden;
}
video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<video loop muted autoplay playsinline id="video"></video>
```

Comment: I freaken love you right now. Spending DAYS trying to figure this out. All examples are of full page! Just wrap in div element and all set.

Comment: Same story as @ShawnRebelo , you're awesome! The only thing I noticed is that it looks like the quality of the video is not as good (less smooth/crisp) as watching it directly on Youtube. Is there anything that could improve the quality?

My youtube vid has 1080p50 . Maybe for the 50 fps a different tag is required?

Comment: @Nicholas Hi. You can extend stream formats and add few more:
`...298: '720p60na', 299: '1080p60na', 264: '1440pna'...` but all of these extra streams has no sound and takes longer to start playing.

Comment: @350D thanks fory our answer, indeed I already found out that I can use 720p50na right now and now it plays fine. I think for some reason I temporarily did not get this streams and that's why I didn't find out immediately. 

I also saw that when on mobile and playing back the 1080p version it looks like it is zoomed in compared to the 720p version. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: @Nicholas check your css for `video` tag ( support for `object-fit` on mobile)

Comment: how to play it with sound? if i just remove *muted* from video tag, video stops playing

Comment: @350D fullscreen not working with edge, IE. at least in my desktop

Comment: @350D This also doesn't seem to work with YouTube streams: http://jsbin.com/fuvofunere/edit?html,css,js,output any idea why?

Comment: Since a few days the solution is not working anymore for my project. Not sure what's wrong I get a 404 in console..

Comment: THIS OPTION IS NO LONGER WORKING DUE TO THE SERVICE BEING SHUT DOWN! Sorry for caps. But ya. Sadly this is no longer an option.

Comment: @ShawnRebelo I'm like you really love his answer and just found out today Yahool retired the service. Please see my answer below and hope it helps.

Comment: Already had a different solution but it's not as good as yours. I might reuse your solution very soon! Thanks!

Comment: @Nicholas I'm constantly looking for easy way for good cors proxy solution like YQL was before and I will update my answers accordingly

Comment: @Nicholas Check my latest update with public Google image proxy! Works just fine!

Comment: Thanks!!! I will delete my post. I used https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ for cors proxy.

Comment: @Frank that one is ok for wireframes or POC projects. With google you can be safe for production with some caching

Comment: @ShawnRebelo Check updated version, it works even better now!

Comment: @350D I see. Thank you for letting me know! I will use your Google's proxy!

Comment: I'm using ACF in Wordpress. My clients have to enter the youtube ID.. But here in the example the id is in the js.. Some way to grab it from my php? :)

Comment: @KeviinCosmos just echo your ID as javascript variable or `data` attribute for any element on the page specific to your widget for example.

Comment: @350D Thanks - but i'm to green in this area. Do you have some links for me, to get in the right direction?

Comment: @350D IT WORKS! But i don't think it's the best solution: Screenshot [link](https://prnt.sc/mj5zby)

Comment: @350D Thank you SO MUCH, this has been bugging me for days/weeks!! This is a great solution and worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @350D any idea why a video might return error 150 with reason ""This video is unavailable." ? The video is public with embedding enabled.

Comment: @350D, Thanks for this great script. It was working fine but suddenly it stopped working and it showed this console error 'The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().'. I have checked your demo and it is also not working now and showed same error. Any idea?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Moorthy Hello! thank you for report! Snippet and JSFiddle example updated already. Youtube implemented new schema for some videos where no streams data available in json root.

Comment: @350D is there any way to add a 'startSeconds' parameter somewhere? I'd like my video to start 10 seconds in.

Comment: Thank you for this one dude. You rock!

Comment: 05.10.2020 - still working. Thank you for solution!

Comment: @Immersion how did you make it work? I'm getting an error in console. Something about CORS policy.

Comment: @jmchauv two options here. 1 - add `loadedmetadata` event listener to `video_tag` and set `video_tag.currentTime = 5`. 2 - add `#t=5,15` to the end of the `video_tag.src` where first number = start, second end in seconds.
}, false);

Answer (score 0):

I found here a [tutorial](http://www.developphp.com/video/CSS/Video-Background-Tutorial-Plus-Youtube-Embed) that explains how to set a video as a background of your page. This tutorial shows how to make the video as a fullscreen background and a background for only a specific page like you want.

You need to set your Html and CSS part to achieve this kind of background. The tutorial page includes some sample code that you can copy.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: The current code does exactly that, or at least I tweaked it slightly to do that. I don't think it's actually possibly to stream a video as the background of a div/section of a page unless you use HTML Video player, which you cannot do with Youtube videos, so I have placed blank boxes over the background through the page to have different backgrounds elsewhere on the same page.

Comment: I have yet to solve it, but have found a temporary way around it, which is a bit crude. If no one can answer my questions shortly, I will deem it no possible as that's the impression I have far from various articles and questions I have read.

Comment: @ThomasSmyth please, check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the above, I actually came up with a different method when the old one died out. Maybe not as good as the above, but it works for me. This is made into a WP Plugin and the user sets the height and a few other options like Video ID, mute and volume. Also using YouTube API.

Can see it here at the top of my website: https://neotropicworks.com/

```
// Output from plugin onto page using 'wp_add_inline_script' to JS file below
var video_id = "qnTsIVYxYkc",video_mute = true,video_volume = 50;

// JS file
var player;
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('youtube-header-player', {
        videoId: video_id,
        playerVars: {
            playlist: video_id,
            loop: 1
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
    if(video_mute){
        player.mute();
    } else {
        player.setVolume(video_volume);
    }
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        player.playVideo(); 
    }
}
```

In a stylesheet

```
.video-wrapper{width: 100%;overflow: hidden;position: relative;}
.video-container {position: absolute;width: auto;top: -50%;left: 0;right: 0;bottom: -50%;}
.video-bg {background: none;position: absolute;top: 0;right: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;z-index: 1;}
.video-bg .video-fg,.video-bg iframe,.video-bg video {position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0 !important;width: 100% !important;height: 100%;}
```

Below is generated output from user on the height they want. They set sizes for the different devices, window sizes for better control.

```
.video-wrapper{height: 400px;}
.video-container {height: 800px;}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .video-wrapper{height: 300px;}
    .video-container {height: 600px;}
}
@media (max-width:767px) {
    .video-wrapper{height: 200px;}
    .video-container {height: 400px;}
}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
    <div class="video-container">
        <div class="video-bg">
            <div class="video-fg" id="youtube-header-player"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing a simple jQuery plugin I've made, to make your lives easier.

You only need to select an element with a `data-youtube` attribute containing a youtube link or ID only. Everything else is done for you by the plugin, including embed api script injection and CSS.

Here is a quick usage sample. You can see it in action [here](https://stamat.github.io/jquery.youtube-background/).

```
<div id="ytbg" data-youtube="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEpEeyqGlxA"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('[data-youtube]').youtube_background();
    });
</script>
```

Code on [GitHub](https://github.com/stamat/jquery.youtube-background).