# Youtube video as background for webpage

Tags: html, css, video, youtube, background

I need youtube video as background for my web page.
This is my code

```
<section class="about-section">

           <div class="video-background">
<div class="video-foreground">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UY9V5S9MEgk?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=W0LHTWG-UmQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div> </div> </section>
```

This is working fine. My issue is I need to use the following youtube video as my background but it is not working.
I tried these two URLs but not working

> https://youtu.be/UY9V5S9MEgk

Theese are URL's I have tried

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UY9V5S9MEgk

Comment: Check my iFrameless/JS/CSS only solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41616179/youtube-video-header-background/45377998#45377998

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the embed code of your youtube video and replace it with your current

```
<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UY9V5S9MEgk?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=W0LHTWG-UmQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div style="position: fixed; z-index: -99; width: 100%; height: 100%">
  <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" 
    src="https://youtube.com/embed/UY9V5S9MEgk?autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this question is already solved [click here][1]

if you have any query please message me.

```
[1]: https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/PZyMrd
```

and [click here][1]

```
  [1]: https://www.labnol.org/internet/youtube-video-background/27933/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<section class="about-section">   
  <div class="video-background">
    <div class="video-foreground">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UY9V5S9MEgk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
      </iframe>
    </div> 
  </div> 
</section>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UY9V5S9MEgk">
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```