# Two Youtube videos as HTML5 videos on one page - Google Image proxy

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, html5-video

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45377998/10678978) js code to import a Youtube video and output as HTML5. It works great, but I'd like to have 2 videos on one page - is there a way to manipulate this code to have 2 videos to different ID's?

I have tried duplicating the code and changing the IDs, but it just displays the last one(obviously) because it's using the same method. I don't really understand the function fully, so any explanation in answers of where I've gone wrong would be great!

This is what I've attempted to adapt from the linked question's code:

```js
var vid = "R3AKlscrjmQ",
  streams,
  video_focused = true,
  video_tag = $("#video"),
  video_obj = video_tag.get(0);
$.get("https://images" + ~~(Math.random() * 33) + "-focus-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy?container=none&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fget_video_info%3Fvideo_id%3D" + vid, function(data) {
  if (data) {
    streams = parse_youtube_meta(data);
    video_tag.attr({
      src: streams['1080p'] || streams['720p'] || streams['360p']
    });

    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
      video_focused = !video_focused ? video_obj.play() : video_obj.pause();
    });
  }
});

var vid2 = "R3AKlscrjmQ",
  streams,
  video_focused = true,
  video_tag = $("#video2"),
  video_obj = video_tag.get(0);
$.get("https://images" + ~~(Math.random() * 33) + "-focus-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy?container=none&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fget_video_info%3Fvideo_id%3D" + vid2, function(data) {
  if (data) {
    streams = parse_youtube_meta(data);
    video_tag.attr({
      src: streams['1080p'] || streams['720p'] || streams['360p']
    });

    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
      video_focused = !video_focused ? video_obj.play() : video_obj.pause();
    });
  }
});




function parse_youtube_meta(rawdata) {
  var data = parse_str(rawdata),
    streams = (data.url_encoded_fmt_stream_map + ',' + data.adaptive_fmts).split(','),
    result = {};
  $.each(streams, function(n, s) {
    var stream = parse_str(s),
      itag = stream.itag * 1,
      quality = false,
      itag_map = {
        18: '360p',
        22: '720p',
        37: '1080p',
        38: '3072p',
        82: '360p3d',
        83: '480p3d',
        84: '720p3d',
        85: '1080p3d',
        133: '240pna',
        134: '360pna',
        135: '480pna',
        136: '720pna',
        137: '1080pna',
        264: '1440pna',
        298: '720p60',
        299: '1080p60na',
        160: '144pna',
        139: "48kbps",
        140: "128kbps",
        141: "256kbps"
      };
    //if (stream.type.indexOf('o/mp4') > 0) console.log(stream);
    if (itag_map[itag]) result[itag_map[itag]] = stream.url;
  });
  return result;
};

function parse_str(str) {
  return str.split('&').reduce(function(params, param) {
    var paramSplit = param.split('=').map(function(value) {
      return decodeURIComponent(value.replace('+', ' '));
    });
    params[paramSplit[0]] = paramSplit[1];
    return params;
  }, {});
}
```

```css
.video-container {
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
  overflow: hidden;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="video-container">
  <video loop muted autoplay playsinline id="video"></video>
</div>

<div class="video-container">
  <video loop muted autoplay playsinline id="video2"></video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding an answer that worked really well and was tidy enough for me to continue to add more videos if i need to.

```js
setupVideo("ScMzIvxBSi4", $('#video'));
setupVideo("ni5hRK1ehzk", $('#video2'));

function setupVideo(videoId, selectorElement) {
  var vid = videoId,
    streams,
    video_focused = true,
    video_tag = selectorElement,
    video_obj = video_tag.get(0);
  $.get("https://images" + ~~(Math.random() * 33) + "-focus-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy?container=none&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fget_video_info%3Fvideo_id%3D" + vid, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data) {
      streams = parse_youtube_meta(data);
      video_tag.attr({
        src: streams['1080p'] || streams['720p'] || streams['360p']
      });

      document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
        video_focused = !video_focused ? video_obj.play() : video_obj.pause();
      });
    }
  });
}

function parse_youtube_meta(rawdata) {
  var data = parse_str(rawdata),
    streams = (data.url_encoded_fmt_stream_map + ',' + data.adaptive_fmts).split(','),
    result = {};
  streams.forEach(function(s) {
    var stream = parse_str(s),
      itag = stream.itag * 1,
      quality = false,
      itag_map = {
        18: '360p',
        22: '720p',
        37: '1080p',
        38: '3072p',
        82: '360p3d',
        83: '480p3d',
        84: '720p3d',
        85: '1080p3d',
        133: '240pna',
        134: '360pna',
        135: '480pna',
        136: '720pna',
        137: '1080pna',
        264: '1440pna',
        298: '720p60',
        299: '1080p60na',
        160: '144pna',
        139: "48kbps",
        140: "128kbps",
        141: "256kbps"
      };
    //if (stream.type.indexOf('o/mp4') > 0) console.log(stream);
    if (itag_map[itag]) result[itag_map[itag]] = stream.url;
  });
  return result;
};

function parse_str(str) {
  return str.split('&').reduce(function(params, param) {
    var paramSplit = param.split('=').map(function(value) {
      return decodeURIComponent(value.replace('+', ' '));
    });
    params[paramSplit[0]] = paramSplit[1];
    return params;
  }, {});
}
```

```css
.video-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="video-container">
  <video loop muted autoplay playsinline id="video"></video>
</div>

<div class="video-container">
  <video loop muted autoplay playsinline id="video2"></video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a different `video_id` -- right now they are duplicates of `video_id: "R3AKlscrjmQ"`. All video variables are assigned as properties to an object. These objects are located in `vidArray`. The first function has been modified to run in a loop and setup the videos associated with each object form `vidArray`. For the sake of clutter, the last two functions are omitted, ***but remember to include them before testing.***

```js
var streams;

var vidArray = [{
  video_id: "R3AKlscrjmQ",
  video_tag: $("#video0"),
  video_focused: true,
  video_obj: document.getElementById("video0")
}, {
  video_id: "?",
  video_tag: $("#video1"),
  video_focused: true,
  video_obj: document.getElementById("video1")
}];

var idx;

for (idx = 0; idx < vidArray.length; idx++) {
  $.get("https://images" + ~~(Math.random() * 33) + "-focus-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy?container=none&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fget_video_info%3Fvideo_id%3D" + vidArray[idx].video_id, function(data) {
    if (data) {
      streams = parse_youtube_meta(data);
      vidArray[idx].video_tag.attr({
        src: streams['1080p'] || streams['720p'] || streams['360p']
      });

      vidArray[idx].video_obj.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function(e, idx) {
        vidArray[idx].video_focused = !vidArray[idx].video_focused ? vidArray[idx].video_obj.play() : vidArray[idx].video_obj.pause();
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.video-page {
  height: 100vh;
  background: orange;
  overflow: hidden;
}

video {
  margin: 50vh auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-page">
  <video loop muted autoplay playsinline id="video0"></video>
</div>
<div class="video-page">
  <video loop muted autoplay playsinline id="video1"></video>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have found a tidier answer (that i've posted below) that just allows you to declare the setup once and then keep adding the video ID's at the top. :-)  Thanks anyway!

Comment: You are calling your function twice and the parameters are passed by hand. My solution accepts an array of objects once. An array of objects is one step away from a JSON which of course is the most common way to tx/rx data like YT settings. Nevertheless, it may appear less tidier but it's design is to be generic and workable with the code and objectives you yourself posted. Anyways good luck with that.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get your example to work - the snippet isn't showing anything either. The example I've found below is working, although it may not be the best way - if you think your answer is better, could you help me to get your example working?

Comment: I never tested it plus I never said it was better, I explained the differences between the two. I don't test video on my phone it's a waste of money. If you plan on updating video content regularly and/or in bulk you should pursue this path. If you just need a few videos that you don't plan on changing anytime soon yours is fine.