# Play Youtube in background header

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I've been using this code to play YouTube videos in the background for some time. I noticed that it stopped working, but I can't find out why. Have there been any recent changes from Youtube?

It seems to me that the problem appears from the line from parse_youtube_meta but I'm not sure.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

```js
var vid = "bvqH6I1sQJQ", // "iGpuQ0ioPrM",
    streams,
    video_focused = true,
    video_tag = $("#video"),
    video_obj = video_tag.get(0);
$.get("https://images"+~~(Math.random()*33)+"-focus-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy?container=none&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fget_video_info%3Fvideo_id%3D" + vid, function(data) {
console.log(data);
    if (data) {
        streams = parse_youtube_meta(data);
        video_tag.attr({
            src: streams['1080p'] || streams['720p'] || streams['360p']
        });

        document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
            video_focused = !video_focused ? video_obj.play() : video_obj.pause();
        });
    } else {
      $('pre').text('Youtube API Error');
    }
});

function parse_youtube_meta(rawdata) {
    var data = parse_str(rawdata),
        streams = (data.url_encoded_fmt_stream_map + ',' + data.adaptive_fmts).split(','),
        result = {};
    streams.forEach(function(s) {
        var stream = parse_str(s),
            itag = stream.itag * 1,
            quality = false,
            itag_map = {
                18: '360p',
                22: '720p',
                37: '1080p',
                38: '3072p',
                82: '360p3d',
                83: '480p3d',
                84: '720p3d',
                85: '1080p3d',
                133: '240pna',
                134: '360pna',
                135: '480pna',
                136: '720pna',
                137: '1080pna',
                264: '1440pna',
                298: '720p60',
                299: '1080p60na',
                160: '144pna',
                139: "48kbps",
                140: "128kbps",
                141: "256kbps"
            };
        //if (stream.type.indexOf('o/mp4') > 0) console.log(stream);
        if (itag_map[itag]) result[itag_map[itag]] = stream.url;
    });
    return result;
};

function parse_str(str) {
    return str.split('&').reduce(function(params, param) {
        var paramSplit = param.split('=').map(function(value) {
            return decodeURIComponent(value.replace('+', ' '));
        });
        params[paramSplit[0]] = paramSplit[1];
        return params;
    }, {});
}
```

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 background: #444;
 overflow: hidden;
}
video {
      object-fit: cover;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
}
pre {
  padding: 1em;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video loop muted autoplay playsinline id="video"></video>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Please see @350D's updated version of this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45377998/292144). It reflects recent (Jan 2020) changes to youtube's stream schema.